# How can I compute a cosine similarity between two large sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, cosine-similarity

I would like to compute the cosine similarity between each pair of row of two giant sparse matrices. The traditional functions compute for all pair of rows, and, in my case, even been more "easy", I didn't find implementation to do that.

For instance: the result will be an array of `cos(A[row i], B[row i]) for all i in N`.

I've already tried using `map` for each pair of row, but was REALLY slow. Now, I have been trying to compute for all row using matrix operations.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

A = sp.csr_matrix((N,N))
B = sp.csr_matrix((N,N))

A_norm = sp.dok_matrix(A.shape)
A_norm[A.nonzero()] = A[A.nonzero()] / A[A.nonzero()].sum(axis=0)

B_norm = sp.dok_matrix(B.shape)
B_norm[B.nonzero()] = B[B.nonzero()] / B[B.nonzero()].sum(axis=0)

AB = (A_norm*B_norm).sum(axis=0)

AA = np.sum(np.sqrt( A_norm*A_norm ), axis=0)
BB = np.sum(np.sqrt( B_norm*B_norm ), axis=0)
AA_BB = (AA*BB)

cos = sp.dok_matrix(AB.shape)
cos[AA_BB.nonzero()] = AB[AA_BB.nonzero()] / AA_BB[AA_BB.nonzero()]
```

The error occurs when I compute (AA*BB) on my code above. The stack is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-244-00be56e17413> in <module>()
      9 AA = np.sum(np.sqrt( A_norm*A_norm ), axis=0)
     10 BB = np.sum(np.sqrt( B_norm*B_norm ), axis=0)
---> 11 AA_BB = (AA*BB)
     12 
     13 cos = sp.dok_matrix(AB.shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __mul__(self, other)
    218         if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
    219             # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
--> 220             return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    221         if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
    222             return N.dot(self, other)

ValueError: shapes (1,70765) and (1,70765) not aligned: 70765 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: For a sparse matrix, `M.sum(0)` produces a dense numpy matrix, with shape (1,n).  With `np.matrix` the `*` operator is matrix multiplication, `dot`, hence the alignment error.  You either have to transpose one, or use `multiply` (check `np.matrix` for the exact method).